# Swift-3: closure with escaping and non-escaping behaviour together

Tags: swift, swift3, closures

I have encountered a situation when a closure may be called inside the function `f1` (in which the closure is passed to) or it may be passed to some other function `f2`.

So now I wonder how should I define escaping behaviour of this closure. I mean should I put `@escaping` or not?

Sample function:

```
func f1(_ completionHandler: ()->()){
    if someFlag == true{
        completionHandler()
        return
    }
    f2(completionHandler)
}

func f2(_ completionHandler: ()->()){
    // some other magic
}
```

Sorry if there are some syntactical errors, (typed the methods here), my question is, what should be type attribute of completionHandler for function `f1`?

Comment: Okey..now I got it. Thanks. The confusion was in the one word: `can`.

Comment: No problem, I figured I might as well move my comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule for when you need `@escaping` is simple – if a closure function argument *can* escape the lifetime of the function call, it *needs* to be marked as `@escaping` (the compiler simply won't let you compile it otherwise).

In your example code, `completionHandler` is not marked as `@escaping` in `f2` – therefore it cannot escape the lifetime of `f2`. Therefore it cannot possibly escape the lifetime of `f1` either, thus you don't need to mark `f1`'s `completionHandler` as `@escaping`.

If however, `f2`'s `completionHandler` *could* escape the lifetime of `f2`, then you *would* have to mark both `f2` and `f1`'s parameters as `@escaping` as it *could* escape the lifetime of both calls.